# Selecting individual documents/objects from MongoDB collection that's in a loop?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, object, ejs

I'm not sure how to word this exactly...but basically in my code I am looping through my MongoDB collection using `forEach` and displaying the objects within them with ejs in a table. I want to make it so that when a user clicks on one of those objects, it takes them to a page with details for just the item they selected, but can't do that because they are displayed via a loop.

For example:
My collection, called `stores`, has objects like `environment`, `store`, and `version`. When I display them with a loop, this is how I do it:

```js
     <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Environment</th>
                <th>Store Name</th>
                <th>Code Version</th>
            </tr>
        <% stores.forEach(function(store){ %>
            <tr>
                <td> <%= store.environment %> </td>
                <td> <%= store.store %> </td>
                <td> <%= store.version %> </td>
            </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </table>
```

and the resulting table looks something like this:

```
Environment | Store Name   | Code Version
-----------------------------------------
QA1         | Oakdale      | 2019.09
QA2         | Westminster  | 2020.03 
QA3         | Garden Grove | 2020.05
```

I want the user to be able to click on, for example, `QA1` and it will direct them to another page for details on QA1. My question is, with the code being displayed as a group via `<%= store.environment %>`, how do I create a link on JUST QA1, or just QA2? Right now if I put a link in the same `td` as `<%= store.environment %>`, that link shows up in every instance of `environment`.

Is there maybe a way through jQuery or something to select the specific environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, you'll just have to check the `environment` property, or whatever property you're using to define if should show the link.

Here's a quick example of how you could do that:

```js
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Environment</th>
            <th>Store Name</th>
            <th>Code Version</th>
        </tr>
    <% stores.forEach(function(store){ %>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <% if (store.environment === "QA1") { %>
                   <a href="/your-url"><%= store.environment %></a>
                <% } else { %>
                   <%= store.environment %> 
               <% } %>
            </td>
            <td> <%= store.store %> </td>
            <td> <%= store.version %> </td>
        </tr>
    <% }); %>
</table>
```

Sorry for any code mistake, I'm doing direct from StackOverflow.

Comment: oh wow...i tried something similar to this and it didn't work so i assumed it would be something more complicated but this works! thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)